# Extract uptime value from bash command (RaspberryPi)

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x, split, raspberry-pi

When using `uptime` I get for example

`17:16:49 up  3:29,  3 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.02, 0.05`

I only want the `3.29` part for my script....
What is the best, simplest way to get exactly that part out of that string keeping in mind, that this value is going to change up to stuff like:

`22:59:49 up  109:32,  7 users,  load average: 0.10, 0.02, 0.05`

I tried with split for example:

```
def getUPTime():
uptime = os.popen('uptime').readline()
uptime1 = uptime.split("up  ")[0]
up = uptime1.rsplit(",")[3]
return up
```

but I get an error `list index out of range`..... and even if it would work I don't think it is a good solution if anything of the output changes during the time the pi is up

I'm thinking about the `replace` option maybe with `regex`

Comment: Try [`re.split(r"[ ,]+", s)[2]`](http://ideone.com/w6l7Zz)

Comment: Use https://pythonhosted.org/uptime/, which gives you platform independence

Comment: Thanks very cool.... might be the easiest way :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Alastair McCormack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1554386/alastair-mccormack) suggests in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36205387/extract-uptime-value-from-bash-command-raspberrypi#comment60044336_36205387), [`uptime`](https://pythonhosted.org/uptime/) might be the best solution.

However, you may use the `[ ,]` regex with `re.split` to split the string with spaces and commas and then get the 3rd element from the resulting array:

[Demo](http://ideone.com/w6l7Zz):

```
import re
s = "17:16:49 up  3:29,  3 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.02, 0.05"
print(re.split(r"[ ,]+", s)[2])
```

Your code will look like:

```
import re
#...
def getUPTime():
    uptime = os.popen('uptime').readline()
    chunks = re.split(r"[ ,]+", uptime) 
    uptime1 = chunks[0]
    up = chunks[2]
    return up
```

Alternative 1:

Get the third word up to the `,`:

```
^(?:\S+\s+){2}(\S+),
```

In [Python](http://ideone.com/0GhJwA):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^(?:\S+\s+){2}(\S+),')
uptime = "22:59:49 up  109:32,  7 users,  load average: 0.10, 0.02, 0.05"
m = p.search(uptime)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uX0pO4/1)

**Alternative 2**

Match and capture what you need and just match what you need to remove and use `re.sub` with:

```
(?s)^.*?\s(\d+:\d+).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gA0eI3/1), and the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/8y28vD):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?s)^.*?\s(\d+:\d+).*')
uptime = "22:59:49 up  109:32,  7 users,  load average: 0.10, 0.02, 0.05"
print(p.sub(r"\1", uptime))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following RegEx in a `.replace()`, the value will be stored in the first (and only) capture group:

```
\d+:\d+:\d+\s*up\s*(\d+:\d+),
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on RegExr**](http://regexr.com/3d353)</kbd>

---

Here is the full code you could use:

```
import re
def getUPTime():
    uptime = os.popen('uptime').readline()
    uptime = re.search('\d+:\d+:\d+\s*up\s*(\d+:\d+),', uptime)
    return uptime.group(1)
```

Comment: thanks could you maybe elaborate on that a bit .... something like that? `return(up.replace("\d+:\d+:\d+\s*up\s*(\d+:\d+),",""))` ?

Comment: @PeterS I updated the answer with the full code you can use

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. I'm going to use the python uptime but thanks a lot for taking the time to show me the REGEX version